# Load strong named assembly regardless of version in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, .net-assembly, assembly-resolution, assemblyresolve

I have written a plugin for an application which uses the Bouncy Castle Library.
This application runs on Windows CE and runs on the .NET Compact Framework.

The Bouncy Castle Library is a strong named assembly and different versions are are supplied depending on what release it is.

My plugin will work regardless of the version.

If this was a full framework device i would use the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve event to redirect to the assembly that exists. However in the Compact Framework this event doesnt exist.

How can i do this in the Compact Framework?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the question.  Is the issue that you are referencing the Bouncy Castle assembly in your project, but at run-time it is a different version than what you were targeting at build time?  You should be able to set the assembly reference to not require specific version right in Visual Studio.

Comment: @tcarvin Yes, the problem is that compile time and runtime bouncy castle dll can be different versions. How can i set that in visual studio?

Comment: Right-click the Reference in Visual Studio and select "Properties".  You should see an editable option in the property sheet.

Comment: If you are referring to the "Specific Version" option then this is not what what does. That option is a compile time check only. Nothing to do with runtime.

Comment: Huh, yeah I guess you are right.  Doesn't bindingRedirect work in the Compact Framework?